# c++ md5 hash not equal to vb.net code socket

Tags: c++, vb.net, md5

> server -> AUTH GateKeeper S :GKSSP\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0r!W\tvM
>
> Client -> AUTH GateKeeper S :GKSSP\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"g@çójDî3(ƒP¡Á"

VB.NET tcp code:

```vb
Do While Stream.CanRead
    responseData = Trim(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data2, 0, bytes))
    Feed = responseData.Split(Chr(13), Chr(10))
    Dim datax As [Byte]()
    For Each line As String In Feed
        If line <> "" Then
            Select Case UCase(Split(line.Trim, " ")(0))
                Case "AUTH"
                    If (Split(line, " ")(2) = "S") And (Split(line, " ")(3) <> ":OK") Then
                        ChOK = ":GKSSP\0\0\0" & Chr(2) & "\0\0\0" & Chr(3) & "\0\0\0" & Challenge_1(Mid(line, InStr(line, "\0\0\0\0\0\0") + Len("\0\0\0\0\0\0"))) & "Sm(" &
                            HexToAsc("e4") & "HS" & HexToAsc("c1") & "M" & HexToAsc("847f8293f98d") & "UC"
                                        
                        message = "AUTH GateKeeper S " & ChOK & vbCrLf
```

VB.NET challenge functions

```vb
Public Function Challenge_1(Challenge As String) As String
    Dim c1 As String, a1 As String, c2 As String, a2 As String
    c1 = "edp{}e|wxrdse}}u666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666" + Challenge
    a1 = HexToAsc(GetIRC7PWD(c1))
    Dim Aaah As New String("\"c, 48)
    c2 = HexToAsc("0f0e1a11170f161d12180e190f17171f") & Aaah & a1
    a2 = HexToAsc(GetIRC7PWD(c2))
    Challenge_1 = a2
End Function

Public Function GetIRC7PWD(source As String)
    Dim md5Hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()
    '  Dim source As String = "edp{}e|wxrdse}}u666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666"
    Dim data As Byte() = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source))
    Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
        sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next i
    Return sBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

The above code authenticates successfully.

My C++ code works fine, until it reads data sent from the `AUTH` and MD5's it. However, it creates the wrong MD5 hash:

```cpp
while (true)
{
    ZeroMemory(buff, 1024);

    int bytesReceived = NetDll_recv(XNCALLER_SYSAPP,Sock, buff, 1024, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {

    }
    if (bytesReceived > 0) {
        std::string Recieved(buff, bytesReceived);
        std::stringstream iss(Recieved);
        while(iss.good())
        {
            std::string SingleLine;
            getline(iss,SingleLine);
            if (!SingleLine.empty()) {
                stringstream ss(SingleLine);
                string s;
                int xUp = 1;
                vector <string> tokens;
                while (getline(ss, s, ' ')) {
                    tokens.push_back(s);
                    xUp++;
                }
                if (tokens[0] == "AUTH" && tokens[2] == "S") {
                    MD5 md5;
                    string ChOK3 = SingleLine.substr(46);
                            
                    string ChallengeCode = "edp{}e|wxrdse}}u666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666" + ChOK3;
                    char* cz = const_cast<char*>(ChallengeCode.c_str());
                    string g1 = md5.digestString( cz );
                    string a1 = hexToASCII(g1);
                    int n = 48;
                    char cx = '\\';
                    string c2 = hexToASCII("0f0e1a11170f161d12180e190f17171f") + std::string(n, cx) + a1;
                    char* c = const_cast<char*>(c2.c_str());
                    string a2 = md5.digestString( c );
                    string a3 = hexToASCII(a2);
                    //string ChOK4 = ChOK + a2 + "Sm(" + hexToASCII("e4") + "HS" + hexToASCII("c1") + "M" + hexToASCII("847f8293f98d") + "UC\r\n";

                    string ChOK4 = "AUTH GateKeeper S :GKSSP\\0\\0\\0\x02\\0\\0\\0\x03\\0\\0\\0" + a3 + "Sm(" + hexToASCII("e4") + "HS" + hexToASCII("c1") + "M" + hexToASCII("847f8293f98d") + "UC\r\n";
                    const char *cstr = ChOK4.c_str();
                    NetDll_send(XNCALLER_SYSAPP, Sock,ChOK4.c_str(),ChOK4.length(), 0);
                }
```

It looks like my code is the same.

Is it because the characters are UTF-16? How can I read the buffer in UTF-16 so that I can properly MD5 the string?

Comment: they are very different, especially how you split input. In vb you find a series of nulls but in c++ you just hard code index 46.  Without knowing input, impossible to know if they are equivalent

Comment: Also `Encoding.Default` is not defined. It *might* be UTF8, or maybe ASCII, or something else. It can vary, so there's no way to know if it's equivalent. You probably won't even get consistent results in the vb version.

Comment: @ravi_elite Why did you post this as a new question, instead of updating your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70887173/)?

Comment: thank you for updating this

Answer (score 0):

The two codes are NOT doing the same thing, which is why they are producing different results.  Differences are highlighted below:

While reading from the socket:

- the VB code is:

  - reading *arbitrary* bytes (without regard to message boundaries)
  - **converting the bytes from UTF-8 to a UTF-16 string** (without regard to codeunit boundaries)
  - **trimming the string**
  - splitting the string on line breaks
  - parsing each line
- the C++ code is:

  - reading *arbitrary* bytes (without regard to message boundaries)
  - **converting the bytes as-is to a `std::string`** (without regard to encoding)
  - splitting the string on line breaks (without trimming it first)
  - parsing each line

Up to this point, given the data shown, the results are *logically* the same for both codes (though *technically* different layouts in memory), even though they are being processed differently.  But even up to this point, both codes are NOT handling the socket data adequately, and there IS potential for data corruption and data loss here.

Now, assuming no corruption/loss has actually occurred, then for the actual `AUTH` command:

- the VB code is:

  - extracting the challenge **from position 37, after the first `"\0\0\0\0\0\0"` substring** (thus, the extracted challenge is **`"\0\0\0r!W\tvM"`**)

    ```
    AUTH GateKeeper S :GKSSP\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0r!W\tvM
    ^                       ^           ^
    1                       25          37
    ```
  - **converting the challenge from UTF-16 to ANSI bytes**
  - calculating an MD5 for those bytes
  - calculating a 2nd MD5 based on the 1st MD5
  - creating a response for the 2nd MD5
- the C++ code is:

  - extracting the challenge **from fixed index 46 (position 47)** (thus, the extracted challenge is **`"tvM"`**)

    ```
    AUTH GateKeeper S :GKSSP\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0r!W\tvM
    ^                       ^           ^         ^
    0                       24          36        46
    ```
  - **getting the challenge's raw UTF-8 bytes**
  - calculating an MD5 for those bytes
  - calculating a 2nd MD5 based on the 1st MD5
  - creating a response for the 2nd MD5

So, the biggest issues I see that you need to fix are the following:

- in both languages, fix the socket reading logic to avoid data loss. Right now, you are extracting all bytes from the socket and throwing away any incomplete lines that are waiting for more bytes to arrive. You need to save all raw bytes from the socket into an intermediate buffer first, and then extract only complete lines from that buffer, leaving behind incomplete lines in the buffer so they can be finished on subsequent reads.
- on the VB side, for ASCII-only data (as you have shown), the conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 to ANSI is loss-less, but for non-ASCII data this will be lossy. Consider converting the UTF-16 data back to UTF-8 instead of ANSI, to match the C++ code.
- on the C++ side, fix the code to extract the server's challenge from the correct string position to match the VB code.

Comment: oh thanks for this info i thought that the fixed position does not change..

Comment: Based on the data you have shown, the VB code is extracting the challenge from position 37 (why not 43? Why is it looking for only `"\0\0\0\0\0\0"` when the data shown contains `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`? Does the challenge really begin with `"\0\0\0"`?), but the C++ code extracts from index 46 instead.

Comment: my c++ code to get the position is wrong thank you

Comment: my vb.net code 
MsgBox(InStr(line, "\0\0\0\0\0\0")) returns 31
MsgBox(InStr(line, "\0\0\0\0\0\0") + Len("\0\0\0\0\0\0")) returns 45

Comment: also its \x02\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0

Comment: There is no possible way that `InStr(line, "\0\0\0\0\0\0")` can return `31` for the data you have shown, it has to return `25` instead. But even if it did return `31`, `Len("\0\0\0\0\0\0")` is 12, and `31+12=43`, not `45` like you claim. So, clearly you are working with different data than you have shown here.

Comment: ok i went ahead and uploaded exactly what it sends as a binary file 

[link]https://tha-row.net/gatekeeper.dat

Comment: In that case, `InStr(line, "\0\0\0\0\0\0")` would return 0, since there is no such substring in `line`. You would need something more like `InStr(line, "\0\0\0"+Chr(2)+"\0\0\0")` instead. It would be helpful to know the ACTUAL format of the `AUTH` command in this situation, and not play these guessing games anymore. It really feels like you are hashing the wrong data to begin with.

Comment: i tried 

`string findstring = "\x02\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0";
         int findstringn = instr(SingleLine, "\x02\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0");
         int findstringLength = findstring.length();
         int math = findstringn + findstringLength;
         string ChOK3 = SingleLine.substr(math);
`


`int instr(string istring, string tofind){
    if (istring.find(tofind)!=istring.npos){
        return istring.find(tofind)+1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}`

Comment: `"\x02\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0"` is not an escaped string in VB.NET, like it is in C++. `"\x02"` is treated as the literal characters ```\``` `x` `0` `2`, just as `"\0"` is treated as the literal characters ```\``` `0`.  Those are the actual characters used in the `AUTH` data. But ```\``` is an escape character in C++, so `"\x02"` is a single character `0x02` and `\0` is a single character `0x00`. And there is no `instr()` in C++, but there is `std::string::find()`

Comment: `int instr(string istring, string tofind){     if (istring.find(tofind)!=istring.npos){         return istring.find(tofind)+1;     }else{         return 0;     } }`

Comment: <sigh> I give up. It is clear that you don't understand what this `AUTH` data actually holds, and how VB.NET and C++ represent it. Go get yourself a good debugger, and some good books to learn from. I also found some useful info online [here](https://xt.proboards.com/thread/718/msn-chat-authentication-2004), [here](https://gitlab.com/escargot-chat/server/-/issues/34), and [here](http://msn-messenger-protocol.herokuapp.com/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=6&t=5). I'm done dragging this along. I posted my answer, I'm leaving it at that.

Comment: i am just trying to write a irc client for xbox live that connects to irc7 thanks for the information

Comment: just to give u a heads up @Remy Lebeau i fixed the code myself and it connects to irc7 and authenticates properly thanks though